# error importing Design Token library in ts

Tags: typescript, performance, frontend, web-component

hey so I'm trying to implement a feature where you can pass a string containing styles (JSON String) and then I will be using that for styles in CSS for that web component .

```
<comp desingToken='{'key':'value'}'> </comp>
```

and I want to use that it in my definition of comp as `var(--key)` .

but If Im importing `

```
import { DesignToken } from '@microsoft/fast-foundation';
```

Im getting a lot of errors saying :

```
 error TS2344: Type 'T' does not satisfy the constraint 'string | number | boolean | symbol | any[] | Uint8Array | ({ createCSS?(): string; } & Record<PropertyKey, any>) | null'.
  Type 'T' is not assignable to type '{ createCSS?(): string; } & Record<PropertyKey, any>'.
    Type 'T' is not assignable to type '{ createCSS?(): string; }'.

2252 declare function create<T>(nameOrConfig: string): CSSDesignToken<T>;
                                                                      ~

  node_modules/@microsoft/fast-foundation/dist/fast-foundation.d.ts:2252:25
    2252 declare function create<T>(nameOrConfig: string): CSSDesignToken<T>;
                                 ~
    This type parameter might need an `extends { createCSS?(): string; }` constraint.
  node_modules/@microsoft/fast-foundation/dist/fast-foundation.d.ts:2252:25
    2252 declare function create<T>(nameOrConfig: string): CSSDesignToken<T>;
                                 ~
    This type parameter might need an `extends { createCSS?(): string; } & Record<PropertyKey, any>` constraint.
  node_modules/@microsoft/fast-foundation/dist/fast-foundation.d.ts:2252:25
    2252 declare function create<T>(nameOrConfig: string): CSSDesignToken<T>;
                                 ~
    This type parameter might need an `extends string | number | boolean | symbol | any[] | Uint8Array | ({ createCSS?(): string; } & Record<PropertyKey, any>) | null` constraint.
```

I tried different methods of importing and reinstalling the library but nothing helped.

Answer (score 0):

as a temp workaround, you might be able to add `"skipLibCheck": true` to compiler options in tsconfig file.